# Confusion about relationship between operator $K$-theory and topological $K$-theory

Tags: proof-verification, operator-theory, vector-bundles, k-theory, topological-k-theory

I've often heard people say that $K$-theory of $C^*$-algebras generalises topological $K$-theory, for the reason that, say if $M$ is a compact manifold, we have

$K_0(C(M)) = K^0(M)$,

where $C(M)$ denotes the continuous functions on $M$ with values in $\mathbb{C}$.

But the analogous relation doesn't seem to hold for $K_1$: let $M = pt$, then $K_1(C(pt)) = K_1(\mathbb{C}) = 0$, but $K^1(pt) = K^0(S^1 \wedge pt) = K^0(pt) = \mathbb{Z}.$

Have I made a mistake somewhere here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true that $K^1(pt)=K^0(S^1\wedge pt)$, or that $K^1(X)=K^0(S^1\wedge X)$ in general.  This statement is only correct for *reduced* $K$-theory: $\widetilde{K}^1(X)=\widetilde{K}^0(S^1\wedge X)$ for any pointed space $X$ (or you could say $K^1(X)=\widetilde{K}^0(S^1\wedge X)$ since $\widetilde{K}^1$ is the same as $K^1$).  So $K^1(pt)=\widetilde{K}^0(S^1\wedge pt)=\widetilde{K}^0(pt)$ which is indeed trivial.

Comment: So one defines $K^1(X)$ to be $\widetilde{K}^1(X)$? I used to think that $K^1(X)$ was defined as $K^0(SX)$, where $S$ is the unreduced suspension of $X$, but perhaps that's not a useful definition.

Comment: $K^1(X)$ typically defined as $\widetilde{K}^1(X_+)$, but this is isomorphic to $\widetilde{K}^1(X)$.